# Calling a Function from another Class in Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have been trying to call my function from another class into my new class. 
The original function code and class are displayed below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the display alert function in this class like so:

```
class logInViewController: UIViewController{

  var loginError = ViewController().displayAlert("error", message: "What is wrong")
       print(loginError)

   or


   ViewController().displayAlert("error", message: "What is wrong")

}
```

When the code runs it does not display the alert. But if I drag in the function block from the original ViewController class I can then call

```
displayAlert("error", message: "Some Message")
```

With no issue the alert comes up. Not sure what I'm doing wrong I have read other Stack Overflow articles on this but I keep running into the same problem with no display of alert.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get a "view is not in the window hierarchy" error message as a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like there are a few things going on here.

- I am going to guess that `logInViewController` inherits from `ViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. If it doesn't, it should.
- `ViewController().displayAlert(...)` is initializing a `ViewController` instance and then calling `displayAlert(...)` on that instance. The initialized `ViewController` instance is not in the view hierarchy, so the alert will not be displayed anywhere. You should not be calling `ViewController()` anyway.
- Simply calling `displayAlert(...)` without `ViewController()` in front will call the instance method of the current view controller (`self`), which is correct! So, you SHOULD be calling it like this or like `self.displayAlert(...)` (this assumes that `logInViewController` inherits from `ViewController`).

Comment: Sweet man thanks can't believe I missed that small detail. But that is usually what happens, it always helps to have another set of eyes. Thanks again